What's the smallest way to store an HTML canvas image?
I'm trying to make a pixel art animator thing where you can make pixel art but also animate it but the problem is I want the canvas to take up most of my screen with just a little bit of space below it (and it's a square canvas so there will be a lot of space on the sides (for buttons to change the pixel size and color etc) but I just want it to take up most of the window vertically) but I ended up having to set it to like 600x600 or 800x800 pixels (for my large monitor) but that would make the data url take up a lot of space especially if I'm storing a bunch of them for an animation so is there any smaller way to store the canvas image data for each frame (without external/third party compression libraries/frameworks)?
I tried using a smaller canvas (hidden with display: none;) that whenever I drew a larger pixel (e.g. 32x32 pixels image) on the interactive canvas on screen it drew it on the respective pixel on the smaller (hidden) canvas but when I tried to get the image data from the smaller canvas and make a <img> from the smaller canvas data url and make the image bigger again it sometimes gets blurry between the pixels

You could do compression natively

"but that would make the data url take up a lot of space" Data URIs typically use Base64 encoding which automatically adds 33% to the size - 3 bytes of the source are encoded using 4 bytes in the result.

A couple of notes and questions.

You can scale Canvas via CSS as well, so you do not need to handle large pixel sets just because you have a large monitor.
What is this animation to be used for? In some cases you may want to combine the final frames in a SpriteSheet and in others you might even wish to compress to an animation format like MP4.

Anyways, for actually working with the animating part you don't really need to store data URIs yet. You will do fine with the getImageData and putImageData functions and an array. Keeping data in this format can also make it easier to do further JavaScript procedures on it later, without needing to decode and re-encode it.
Here is a rough implementation:


"use strict";
const GetInt = (msg, defaultStr = '') => {
    let n = NaN;
    while (isNaN(n))
        n = parseInt(prompt(msg, defaultStr) ?? '', 10);
    return n;
};
let canvas = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("canvas"));
canvas.style.width = canvas.style.height = `${GetInt(`Pixel size on screen`, '500')}px`;
canvas.style.imageRendering = "pixelated";
canvas.style.border = "1px solid";
canvas.width = canvas.height = GetInt(`Actual pixel resolution`, '32');
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d", { willReadFrequently: true });
let frameIndex = 0;
let canvasFrames = [];
let frameInput = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("input"));
frameInput.type = "number";
frameInput.min = "0";
frameInput.step = "1";
frameInput.placeholder = frameInput.placeholder = `Current Frame`;
frameInput.value = `${frameIndex}`;
let frameSave = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("button"));
frameSave.textContent = `Save current frame`;
let framePlay = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("button"));
framePlay.textContent = `Play`;
function SaveFrame() {
    canvasFrames[frameIndex] = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
function LoadFrame() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    if (canvasFrames[frameIndex]) {
        ctx.putImageData(canvasFrames[frameIndex], 0, 0);
    }
}
let playing = false;
async function Play() {
    if (playing) {
        playing = false;
        return;
    }
    playing = true;
    while (playing) {
        await new Promise(res => requestAnimationFrame(res));
        frameIndex++;
        LoadFrame();
        frameInput.value = `${frameIndex}`;
    }
}
framePlay.addEventListener('click', Play);
canvas.addEventListener('click', evt => {
    let ratio = canvas.width / parseFloat(canvas.style.width.replace(/\D/img, ''));
    let x = Math.round(evt.offsetX * ratio);
    let y = Math.round(evt.offsetY * ratio);
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
});
const OnFrameChange = () => {
    let f = parseFloat(frameInput.value);
    if (isNaN(f))
        return;
    frameIndex = f;
    LoadFrame();
};
frameInput.addEventListener("change", OnFrameChange);
frameInput.addEventListener("input", OnFrameChange);
frameSave.addEventListener("click", SaveFrame);



